# Tags appear through spoilers

Tags: bug, tags, spoilers

When using tags in spoilers, the tags appear through the spoilers, for example:

> This is a spoiler, here is a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag).

Which, if you look carefully, also makes the tag text visible.

Which, kinda invalidates the point of the spoilers...